# Display UNIQUE options in a dropdown menu with Angular2 using an array of objects fetched from firebase

Tags: angular, firebase

Using Angular2, I have a dropdown menu in my html file that looks like this (I'm using Ink as my CSS framework):

```
    <li class="submenu">
      <a href="#">Role in the Organization</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
          <div *ngFor="let currentRole of getUniqueRoles(members)">
            <li>
              <a (click)="changeFilterStrings('role', currentRole)">
                {{currentRole}}
              </a>
            </li>
          </div>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

I am able to confirm that members works correctly, because other html downstream in the same template works.

The problem (I think) is that the members array is retrieved asynchronously. It seems that something like `*ngFor="let currentRole of getUniqueRoles(members) | async"` doesn't seem to work. I gladly welcome advice! I'm guessing from similar questions that a pipe is the answer, but I'm not quite sure how to implement if I want to filter by a property of member.

Currently, the dropdown displays nothing. To clarify, I see the "Role in the Organization" option, but its own dropdown is populated a blank rectangle."

The typescript of the same component, for reference:

```
getUniqueRoles(members: Member[]){
    var flags = [], output = [], l = members.length, i;
    for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
      if( flags[members[i].role]) continue;
      flags[members[i].role] = true;
      output.push(members[i].role);
    }
    return output;
  }
```

My members model:

```
export class Member {
  public dateCreated: Date = new Date();
  public TWITTERPOPULATION: number = 328000000; // TODO figure of how to globally access this as a const
  public TOTALWORLDWEALTH: number = 60000000000;
  public influenceQuotient: number;

  constructor(public firstName: string, public lastName: string, public illuminatiNickname: string, public sectorOfInfluence: string, public numberOfTwitterFollowers: number, public netWorth: number, public politicalImpactQuotient: number, public suspicionOfIlluminatiMembership: number, public role: string, public salientDetails: string, public imgURL: string, public imgAlt: string) {
    this.influenceQuotient = numberOfTwitterFollowers/this.TWITTERPOPULATION + netWorth/this.TOTALWORLDWEALTH + politicalImpactQuotient - suspicionOfIlluminatiMembership;
  }
}
```

members[] is just an array of Member objects (but fetched from fireBase).

Comment: Can you provide what's the `members[]` structure?

Comment: Does the update help?

Comment: What is `members`? Maybe an `Observable` given your attempt at inserting the `async` pipe? How is that property being set and how are you using it *"elsewhere in your template"*? Note that your method to remove duplicates does not deal with an `Observable` as either input or output (so the async pipe will not work, and neither will the input). If the original source at least is an `Observable` then you probably want `.distinct()` on that source at some point instead. Best to show where the source is coming from if you can't work out from those notes.

Comment: Thanks, Neil. Yes, it's a FirebaseListObservable<any[]>. Any leads on where I might find documentation for .distinct()? I'm unfamiliar.